# How do I set a max quantity in darryldecode shopping cart in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
            \Cart::add(array(
                'id' => $request->test,
                'name' => $price->tests->item_name,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price' => $price->price,
                'attributes' => array(
                    'lab_logo' => $price->labs->logo,
                    'lab_name' => $price->labs->name,
                    'item_number' => $price->tests->item_number
                ),
            ));
```

When i add the same product it increments the item quantity but i want the quantity of the item to be 1 at max.

Comment: You'll need to see if the item exists in the cart before attempting to add it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart):

```php
// NOTE: as you can see by default, the quantity update is relative to its current value
// if you want to just totally replace the quantity instead of incrementing or decrementing its current quantity value
// you can pass an array in quantity value like so:
Cart::update(456, array(
  'quantity' => array(
      'relative' => false,
      'value' => 5
  ),
));
```

So, if you pass an array on add and override it to not be **relative**, it should work as expected:

```php
Cart::add(array(
   'id' => $request->test,
   'name' => $price->tests->item_name,
   'quantity' => array(
      'relative' => false,
      'value' => 1,
   ),
   'price' => $price->price,
   'attributes' => array(
      'lab_logo' => $price->labs->logo,
      'lab_name' => $price->labs->name,
      'item_number' => $price->tests->item_number
   ),
));
```

Comment: Using this, im getting this error Darryldecode\Cart\Exceptions\InvalidItemException
validation.numeric

Comment: I just checked their source code and it appears the add() method does not do the relative quantity. Looks like your options are to loop through the cart and check if already exists, or call `update()` immediately after adding and use the non-relative quantity as described in the docs.

Comment: using the comment @aynber gave, i was able to make it work